# "A base of ..." plural or singular

Tags: grammatical-number

I would like to say the number of my trial users grow every day by "I have a base of trial users, which grow every day".

Should I use "grow" or "grows"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grows. Figure out what the subject of the sentence is (who is growing? The base or the users? Answer: it's the base) Take out all of the extra words and see what makes sense:

1. The base grow
2. The base grows

Number 2 is correct.